# Tag Highlighting

Tags: support, tags

I find the following behavior weird, am I the only one?  I haven't found any other questions here or in UV that address this "issue".

Click on "Questions"

- (My Interesting Tags get highlighted)
- Click on a tag from "Interesting/Related Tags" list to filter by, which is also marked as one of your Interesting Tags
- (Nothing gets highlighted anymore)

Click on "Unanswered"

- (My Interesting Tags get highlighted)
- Click on a tag from "Unanswered Tags" list to filter by, which is also marked as one of your Interesting Tags
  section
- (Everything gets highlighted)
- OR Click on a tag from "Interesting Tags" and you get redirected to the "Questions" section

Wouldn't it be best if once you click on a tag to filter by, only the items that contain additional tags which you have marked as interesting get highlighted?

Edit: And why would clicking on Interesting Tags from the "Unanswered" section redirect you to the "Question" section and not the unanswered questions with that tag?

Answer (score 3):

For the first point: I think they're not highlighted because you're looking at an interesting tag, so naturally *all* of them would be highlighted - and that doesn't add any value.  I'm not sure that highlighting ones that contain any other interesting tags would help - you already know they're interesting... is a question about mysql + php more interesting than a question about php?  I don't think so when you've chosen to look at the php tag.

As for your second point - could not reproduce.  I just got taken back to Questions

Comment: I agree with you on there being no value added on highlighting all the items if you filtered by that tag, that's my point.  I noticed what you mean you get taken back to Questions.  If you click on Interesting Tags you get taken back to Questions.  If you click on Unanswered Tags you get the behavior I explained (editing post).

Comment: That's weird... I clicked on an unanswered tag and it took me to the right URL but didn't filter the questions at all.

Comment: Ah, I was on the "my tags" tab - guess that's a separate issue

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your first scenario, I see *everything* highlighted. And I'm here because I, too, think that highlighting everything is... a bit annoying, and certainly not useful. But where to log this wishlist bug?  Here?

EDIT: And I agree with your "if I filter by one of my favorite tags, highlight those questions with additional tags I favor". Was my first thought when I saw the filter display.